# Android shape: Layer-list scale or fit to View it is assigned to

Tags: android, xml

I am making a layer-list at the moment. I would like one of the two following:

- For my layer-list to scale to fit the view which it is assigned to, imageview/view src or background. So for example if I was to set width and height both to 20dp on the imageview/view, my layer-list would scale to fit the imageview/view dimensions
- For my imageview/view to scale depending on the dimensions of the layer-list.

I do not wish to manually set height and width in both my layer-list and imageview/view. How is this accomplished?

Comment: So basically what you want is to set `wrap_content` on imageview so it scales to the size of the drawable which is dependant on the size of imageview itself? Have you set the src of the ImageView?

Comment: @hoomi indeed! wrap content results in the image not being displayed due to the background on a view not being "content" hence results in 0dp. On the imageview it just doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried setting `minHeight` and `minWidth`?

Comment: 1) Background drawables are already scaled to view dimensions. 2) You need drawables with intrinsic width and height as the layers, such as a shape with defined dimensions or an image file.